# location.href not working after ajax (more detail)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, window.location

When the ajax call succeeds, the callback function is executed. The function in the callback function does not work in any way.

My code is :

```
    sendAjax(url, data, method, async, callBackFn, IgnoreException) {
         $.ajax({
            type:method,
            async:async,
            url:url,
            data:data
            timeout:timeout,
            beforeSend:function(xmlHttpRequest) {
              xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("AJAX", "true");
            },
            success:function(data) {
               try {
                 var responseText = $.parseJSON(data);
                 if (responseText.error_code && !IgnoreException) {
                    alert(responseText.error_msg);
                    var fnName = responseText.LOGIN||{};
                    if (typeof window[fnName] == 'function') {
                       var args = responseText.LOGIN_PARAM||{};
                       window[fnName](args);
                    }
                 } else {
                    callBackFn($.parseJSON(data));
                    return;
                 }
               } catch(e) {
                 ~~~~~~~~~
               } finally {
               }
            }

})

}
```

.
.
.
.

```
sendAjax("mo/serviceAction.do", $("#form").serialize(), "post", true, callback);
```

.
.
.
.

```
function callback(param) {
   alert("Here!");
   location.href = "intent://host&params#intent;scheme='scheme';package=package";
}
```

However, if a function that was not executed after ajax call is executed as a click event on the button tag, the **location.href** is executed...
But, alert("Here!") is working!!

Why are the two situations different?

And what if i want to run location.href directly in the callback?

Comment: You don't pass a value for the `IgnoreException` parameter, which is therefore `undefined`, which means `!IgnoreException` always evaluates to true. Not entirely sure I understand your issue though. But I don't see how your callback function can ever be called.

Answer (score 1):

There is a misspelling you have acllBackFn as a parameter name.

```
sendAjax(url, data, method, async, acllBackFn, IgnoreException)
```

And later on.

```
callBackFn($.parseJSON(data));
```

Comment: you forgot an `)`